# How to get the `BroadcastReceiver` instance which is defined in `AndroidManifest.xml`

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcastreceiver

I have a `BroadcastReceiver` in my app, and it was defined in `AndroidManifest.xml` as below:

```
<receiver android:name=".receiver.MyTaskReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="xxx.xxx.xxx" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

This is the `MyTaskReceiver` code :

```
public class MyTaskReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private ReceiverListener listener ;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //do general things

        if(listener != null) {
            listener.received();    //do special things if the listener is setted up.
        }
    }

    public void setListener(ReceiverListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public interface ReceiverListener {
        void received();
    }

}
```

When the receiver got a intent, I will do some general things first, like save data...

But if the specified activity is displayed to the user, I need to do change the activity's views, so I use the `ReceiverListener` to do this. Set a listener to the `MyTaskReceiver` in `onCreate` and set `null` in `onDestroy`.

Then here comes an issue, how can to get the instance of the `MyTaskReceiver` so that I can set a listener to it?

Or is there any other ways to achieve what I want ?

Thanks.

Comment: You do not need the reference to a receiver when it is defined in Manifest file. Just handle the intent in your BroadcastReceiver class.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not how receivers works. The instance will be created, the `intent` delivered to `onReceived` and then destroyed. You can't register listener to it. Take a look on @Natalia answer. That seems to be what you're looking for.

Comment: @Budius your comment is the answer I want, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can register receiver in your activity like this:

```
private void registerBroadcastReceiver() {
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(xxx.xxx.xxx);
    registerReceiver(this.broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
}

private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        //do whatever need to be done
    }
};
```

Hope it helps! :)

And remember to unregister your receiver (for example in `onDestroy()`)

```
unregisterReceiver(this.broadcastReceiver);
```

Comment: I know I can register BroadcastReceiver in an activity, but my receiver doesn't depend on a special activity, I need it works when the app is running not an activity is running.  And thanks anyway :)